# Redirect all 404 error pages to custom 404 page Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created a custom 404 not-found method in my home controller

I've set `$route['404_override'] = 'home/notfound';

and it works well for not found url's right after the main domain (e.g. www.domain.com/uroetiuosyerit)

but if i type in a class name then a invalid url (e.g. www.domain.com/services/yersityijftnyutyum) it's showing the default codeigniter 404 content

I'm using codigniter 3 with `hmvc` modeler extension https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: so home is a controller and notfound a function?right? where is home located? you will need to take it out of the hmvc structure, to provide a "catch all"

Comment: but i wanna use my template module to display a nice styled 404 page, so how do i cal a  "module" from a plain codeigniter controller?

Answer (score 4):

set up a **route** like this for example:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'errormanager/my404';
```

then a **controller** `errormanager` with a function like:

```
public function my404(){

    $data['menu']=$this->Sitemanager->get_menu();

    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('custom404');
    $this->load->view('footer');    
}
```

and a **view** `custom404.php` like this:

```
<div class="my404"> 404 this page does not exist</div>
```

As you use the HMVC approach, make sure that the controller `errormanager` and the view can be reached from everywhere, which means you need to locate it right in the Codeigniter controller+view folder (application\views and application\controller) and not in the extended modules HMVC structure

Answer (score 0):

Create controller like My404 in **application/controlers** folder and add follow code:

```
<?php defined ('BASEPATH') or exit ('No direct script acces allowed');

class My404 extends CI_Controler {

  public function __construct()
  {
  parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
  $this->output->set_status_header('404');
  $this->load->view('err404');
  }

}
```

Next, set up the route in the **application/config/routes.php** file:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';
```

Now, you create view in **application/view** folder and add follow code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php
$ci = new CI_Controller();
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('url');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>404 Page</title>
  </head>
<body>
 <div>
  <p>How to Create Custom Codeigniter 404 Error Pages </p>
   <div>
    <p><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Go Back to Home</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can customize from your theme or template.