# How can I redirect 404 page to home page in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect all 404 error custom pages to home page in codeigniter if someone type something after proper url then user redirect to home page.

Comment: can you post what that "proper url" is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230552/redirect-all-404-error-pages-to-custom-404-page-codeigniter-hmvc

Answer (score 1):

First, go to config -> routes, then scroll down until you found

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error404'; //by default it's '' (empty)
```

Second, you create a controller Error404.php

```
<?php
class Error404 extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        redirect('home'); //your controller (like Home.php or any controller that you want to call)
    }
}
```

Comment: also, if you ask why I create new controller rather than put the home controller in the override:
You can directly call 'home' controller from 404_overide, it will direct you to home as well. But the address bar will not be updated (for example if you put www.yourdomain.com/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx if you call 'home' directly from 404_overide you will be directed to home, but the address bar stay www.yourdomain.com/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx, not www.yourdomain.com/home.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
class Error extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  function index(){
    $this->load->view('home');
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit error_404.php file `(FilePath: application/views/errors/html/error_404.php)`

Add your code before `</body>` tag like this:

```
<?php
header("Location: $yourhomepageurl");
```